# Restricting action result from the base controller depending on a record in a mode

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

i want to restrict a user from accessing a controller depending on it's access level in a table. access level and role code. how would i'll do it?? i've tried

```
protected override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext context)
    {
        if (context.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {

            string acceslevel = oSYSWUSER.acclvl_cd;
            string role_cd = ROLE_CD.ToString();
            string asd = oSYSMENU.action_nm;

        }
    }
```

i want to check the models data for the record first if the access level is equal to the access level of a user. i want to achieve this because the users are restricted by their roles in our old system which we mount in our current .NET project

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own attribute class, like i do in my project:

```
public class AutorizeCheckAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public AutorizeCheckAttribute()
    {
    }

    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        // or other auth code here
        return httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
    }
}
```

Then you shoul use this attribute on your controllers:

```
[AutorizeCheck()]
public class DepartmentNamesController : Controller
{
    // controller code here
}
```

Comment: how would i read data from my model to compare my current user value??

Comment: use `httpContext.Request`, it contains all request variables

Comment: but the users table is in other model. i would check it with the value from Httpcontext.Request thats what i want to achieve

Comment: You should query needed data from DB. Something like `dbContext.UsersTable.Any(user => user.UserName.equals(httpContext.Request["userName"]))`

Comment: im already in the way of solving it. I am using the baseController class for the validation and onAuthorize thanks for the help